# Unable to read file from DBFS mount

Tags: python, json, pyspark, databricks

I am using Python code in Databricks to read a JSON using the below code.

```
my_json = ''
with open('/dbfs/mnt/my_mount/my_json.json', 'r') as fp:
    my_json = json.load(fp)
```

But I am getting the below error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/mnt/my_mount/my_json.json'
```

However, if I try to read using a Spark Dataframe, I am able to read contents of the json file and verified using `.show()` method of Spark Dataframe.

```
df = spark.read.text('/dbfs/mnt/my_mount/my_json.json', wholetext=True)
```

How can I read the file using `with open`?

Below is the Databricks Runtime I am using.

[image]

Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318402/read-write-single-file-in-databricks

Comment: Its similar but that questions requirement is to append to a file although that user is getting file not found error. @Sharma

Comment: Comment by @Sharma is correct. For Databricks suggest using `dbutils` for direct (non-data frame) file access on blob storage. Otherwise try python lib `S3FS` for AWS or equivalent for azure

Comment: @Sarath Subramanian, which databricks are you using aws or azure?